# how to Dynamically change the contents of the div without flickering in js

Tags: javascript, html, lottie

Welcome, well, I have 10 lottie animations, and I want to show them one by one in the same div. When a certain button is pressed, I do a function for each animation and at the beginning of the function I remove all the contents of the div to display the new content, but as is clear This causes flickering, I was wondering if there is a smarter method that does not cause flicker, please note that I am considered a beginner in website development

here is a link
http://animationstest.atwebpages.com/ , use W,A,D,S to move , It is not responsive so use a pc

But notice that when you quickly press a and then d for example, Flickr does not happen

```
    <script>
    var animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
      container: document.getElementById('bm'),
      renderer: 'svg',
      loop: false,
      autoplay: true,
      path: 'idle.json',
  
  });


    var state = "idle";
    document.onkeydown = function(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if(state === "idle"){
      if(key===65){
          leftmove();
     }
     if(key===68){
          rightmove();
     }
     if(key===87){
          upmove();
     }
     if(key===83){
          downmove();
     }
    }
    if(state === "leftmove"){
      if(key===68){
       leftback();
     }
    }
    if(state === "rightmove"){
      if(key===65){
          rightback();
     }
    }
    if(state === "upmove"){
      if(key===83){
          upback();
     }
    }
    if(state === "downmoved"){
      if(key===87){
          downback();
     }
    }

   }

    function leftmove(){
        document.getElementById('bm').innerHTML = "";
     animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
      container: document.getElementById('bm'),
      renderer: 'svg',
      loop: false,
      autoplay: true,
      path: 'leftmove.json',
  
    });
    state = "leftmove";
    }

    function leftback(){
        document.getElementById('bm').innerHTML = "";
       animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
      container: document.getElementById('bm'),
      renderer: 'svg',
      loop: false,
      autoplay: true,
      path: 'leftback.json',
  
    });
    state = "idle";
    }

    function rightmove(){
        document.getElementById('bm').innerHTML = "";
       animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
      container: document.getElementById('bm'),
      renderer: 'svg',
      loop: false,
      autoplay: true,
      path: 'rightmove.json',
  
    });
    state = "rightmove";
    }
    function rightback(){
        document.getElementById('bm').innerHTML = "";
      animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
      container: document.getElementById('bm'),
      renderer: 'svg',
      loop: false,
      autoplay: true,
      path: 'rightback.json',
  
    });
    state = "idle";
    }

    function upmove(){
        document.getElementById('bm').innerHTML = "";
       animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
      container: document.getElementById('bm'),
      renderer: 'svg',
      loop: false,
      autoplay: true,
      path: 'upmave.json',
  
    });
    state = "upmove";
    }
    function upback(){
        document.getElementById('bm').innerHTML = "";
       animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
      container: document.getElementById('bm'),
      renderer: 'svg',
      loop: false,
      autoplay: true,
      path: 'upback.json',
  
    });
    state = "idle";
    }

    function downmove(){
        document.getElementById('bm').innerHTML = "";
       animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
      container: document.getElementById('bm'),
      renderer: 'svg',
      loop: false,
      autoplay: true,
      path: 'downmove.json',
  
    });
    state = "downmoved";
    }
    function downback(){
      document.getElementById('bm').innerHTML = "";
      animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
      container: document.getElementById('bm'),
      renderer: 'svg',
      loop: false,
      autoplay: true,
      path: 'downback.json',
  
    });
    state = "idle";
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `innerHTML` is your enemy in all this

Comment: @AndreaGiammarchi - That's exactly what I was about to go looking for. Perhaps a case for using the html `<template>` element. It's (the code in this question)  un-testable, so I'll leave my interaction at this comment.

Comment: @AndreaGiammarchi It is possible, but is there any replacements ?

Comment: if you could setup a codepen or something to showcase your flicking, we might be able to help ... without a reproducible flicking, it's a "*guessing game*" and nothing else.

Comment: @enhzflep - i will provide a link to test it ,Just a moment

Comment: http://animationstest.atwebpages.com/ , use W,A,D,S to move , It is not responsive so use pc

Comment: Looks like it happen whenever you hit a key that triggers in a valid direction

Comment: @CoderPi-Exactly, this shape is as you can see inside the div, so when someone presses a button, he deletes the shape in the div and then adds the new shape, which is in the desired direction according to the button that was pressed, but as you see this deletion and addition process causes flicking

Comment: But notice that when you quickly press a and then d for example, Flickr does not happen

Comment: interseting, now presing a-d quickly I got two versions of the game. Two SVG elements. Didn't have the to look at the code yet, but looks like you are creating an entire new svg every time?

Comment: Yes , Exactly I'm sure there is a better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find another way to do what I was doing better, faster and more intelligent, for those who care, I'll explain what I did, simply what I was trying to do is to view a simple svg on the basis of the button that is pressed so I had to delete the old svg and view a new svg every time the user presses  W, S, A, D on the keyboard  But this Take it off and put it in causes Flickr and in people with slow internet speeds, switching to the new svg may be delayed more than a second,

What i did is that i used an js animation engine, which can animate your elements by using simple code, the best one I've found is :
https://github.com/juliangarnier/anime